# Accessing an instance of an object from a different application

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I'm working on a program where i have to read several excel files to populate an instance of an object of a complex class. It has many methods and properties of different types, from double to nested lists of objects from other custom classes in the project. Is there a way to store the instance i created for future reference? I want to use that specific instance in a different project without reading all the excel files again.

For example let my class be `Book.cs`.

```
public class Book
{      
     public string title; 
     public string author;
     public string publisher;
     public int publishYear;
     public int pages;
     public LibraryRef refInfo;  //another custom class with properties.
}
```

There's also a method that reads an excel file and sets the properties above. Then in `Main` i create an instance of Book class.

```
Book b = new Book();
b.ReadExcelFile("excelFile"); //sets the properties of the instance.
```

I want to be able to access the values of the properties of `b` from a different project, anytime i want.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a in-memory shared cache for your project during it's runtime and access the cached object if it's from another module in the same application.

Since it's a different application, there would be no shared memory. So your best bet to avoid parsing the excel file is to serialize the object into a file (in a common file location) and deserialize it back. If you are not keen on using a file system, you could also use azure blob storage.

See Binary Formatter Usage for Serialization and Deserialization.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you mean something like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813/en-us)? I researched serialization to understand the concept but I saw only simple examples with xml and binary serialization. I wasn't sure if it would support properties with custom classes(ex: LibraryRef type above). I guess I have to try and see if serialization works.

Comment: You are somewhat on the correct track. However, there are different [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) of serialization.